# How to use а private repository with VSCode?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

A novice here, please type a small instruction describes how to use a private GitHub repo in VSCode

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To configure a private repo, you first need to generate a public/private RSA key pair on your dev machine to be able to establish an ssh connection to your repo instead of an HTTP connection.

Just install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) in your development environment. During installation, please make sure that you have checked the option to include git bash, as you'll need it to create this key. Once installed, right click on your Windows user folder, select on Open git bash and then just run `ssh-keygen` (or if you are using Linux, you can just `ssh-keygen`) and go through the wizard.

This step will create a hidden .ssh folder that contains your public/private RSA key pair. Navigate to that folder.

The goal here with these keys is to configure your public key on GitHub. Open your id_rsa.pub file with notepad and copy its entire content. Then go to GitHub and under your user Settings > SSH keys just add a key and paste your entire public key plus an arbitrary name.

Now restart VS Code and press `CTRL`+ ' (Backtick) to open PowerShell and then run:

In case you haven't cloned your repo:

- `git clone git@github.com:{UserName}/{RepoName}.git`

To Upload changes to your repo:

- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "{Name for this commit}"`
- `git push {Repo Origin name (default = Origin)} {Branch Name (Default = Master)}`

Note. {} are for reference, do not include them in your commands.

VS Code has built-in support for Source Control, so if it is configured, VS Code will automatically detect changes and get them ready to commit with just a commit message and click. Also, there's a really good VS Core extension called [GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/). This can help you to 1-click push

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's working, it was really helpful, see ya, meh

Answer (score 6):

As of now (july 2019, not sure when this got added exactly) you can do this from within VSCode, just hit <kbd>F1</kbd> in windows or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on mac) to access the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) of VSCode, then type or select `Git: Clone` and finally enter the URL of your repository, so something like https://github.com/MY_USERNAME/MY_PROJECT.git, finally choose the folder you want to use for your cloned repository (open the main folder that contains all your projects, no need to manually create a sub folder for the project itself, git will do this for you using the projects name)

To find your exact repository URL, open the projects github page and click on the green button on the top right that says ["Clone or download"](https://help.github.com/en/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use), if you wonder if you should use HTTPS or SSH check out the [github documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)

Comment: VSCode apparently has issues with ssh .... I could only get https working. Very sad.

Answer (score 4):

I had trouble with cloning a private repository from Github with VSCode. In my case the problem was that I followed Github docs instructions to generate SSH keys with Ed25519 algorithm and using these keys (`id_ed25519.pub`) with VScode and Github did not work for me.

I generated new keys with the RSA algorithm:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

and after adding `id_rsa.pub` to my Github account settings VSCode started working with private repositories.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this did not work in my case: I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129758).

Comment: This was helpful, I think github may have changed UI / documentation so I added some extra steps in my answer.

Comment: when you generate ssh-key on windows it usually goes to C:/Users/username/.ssh inside there you should find id_rsa.pub and id_rsa, you can change those to your own set of private keys and upload your keys to github and should work.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem- but solution was simple:
Mistake was: in windows when you create a keys name should be "id_rsa" (windows cmd suggest rename yor keys).
if your key name is different simple rename private and public keys to "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub"
Then add keys via: ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa (edit path if files in different).
Then add id_rsa.pub key to github profile settings(copy paste of content).
Now you can work with private repositories.

Answer (score 1):

If [Git](https://gitforwindows.org/) is already installed

- Copy the URL of your private repository
- Go to the version control in VS Code
- Click on clone repository (authentication required if not done already) and
- Paste the copied URL in the edit text box as shown in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_cloning-a-repository).

Comment: This worked for me. I loaded the public rsa key but AFAIK, didn't have to use it, as I never declared the private key anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel summed it up but quick read for anyone who's having issues with generating ssh/adding it to github.

As @Kennet stated use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"` hit enter through, it will default to `C:Users` most likely.

Copy the `ida_rsa.pub` generated in github go to `Setting -> Deploy keys` (documentation I saw was outdated) and paste it in and name it ida_rsa.pub.

Note: Make sure to select `"Allow write access`" otherwise your pushes will be denied

If you want multiple ssh keys, [this](https://gist.github.com/aprilmintacpineda/f101bf5fd34f1e6664497cf4b9b9345f) document explains how