# How do I clone a private git repo with ssh in vscode?

Tags: git, github, ssh, visual-studio-code

I'm using mac and I was wondering how can I clone a private github repo with ssh using vscode? I looked at code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol but I couldn't find anything about cloning with ssh.

In vscode I go to the source control icon on the left and click clone repository. I enter `git@github.com:username/project` and it says permission denied. I do have my public and private key generated but where do I enter them?

Comment: This guide is the best https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671825/how-to-use-%D0%B0-private-repository-with-vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ssh is something which you set in your ssh-agent and it works with bash. I have been using Vscode for quite some time and i always setup ssh using git bash which is easier. I clone a project into my workspace using git bash and then open it with vscode.

As far as I can see, there is no way you can setup ssh from vscode.

if you are looking to setup ssh from terminal, docs are [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

Answer (score 8):

I just went through this today. I'm assuming you already have Git for Windows installed and have generated the ssh keys located in your user's "*.ssh*" folder.
After that, you must go to the settings in your GitHub account online and look for the **"SSH and GPG Keys"** option in the menu on the left:

[image: GitHub accounts settings SSH and GPG Keys menu item]

This is where you have to enter your public key by opening the **"id_rsa.pub"** file and then copying its contents into your GitHub account by clicking "New SSH key":

[image: Enter your public key by copying the contents of the id_rsa.pub file from the .ssh folder]

Then you can just use vscode like you would with a regular HTTP connection. Just *Crtl+Shift+P* to open vscode's Command Pallet, select git: clone, paste the SSH address of GitHub repo you want. In order to get the SSH address when you click the green "Clone or Download" button on a GitHub repo you must also click **"Clone with SSH"** in the box that pops up so you copy the SSH address instead of using the HTTPS link.

The only hangup you may have is, the first time you try ssh in vscode it will say, "host cannot be identified" The way to fix this is to simply do a *git clone* from a git bash command line outside of vscode so you can type "yes" to when it asks you if it's ok to add GitHub's SSH key fingerprint.

```
ROB@WINDOW10 MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ git clone git@github.com:Rob4226/example.git
Cloning into 'Example Repo'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? **yes**
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.114.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

For whatever reason the vscode git source control UI doesn't show this message for you to respond so it just throws an error. But after you say "yes" the first time in a git bash command line, ssh will work in vscode from now on without issue. It works great and is so much faster! I never use HTTPS anymore from vscode.

Or, you can manually add GitHub's SSH key fingerprints to your *"known_hosts"* file in the *.ssh* folder. They can be found here: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

```
GitHub's SSH key fingerprints
Public key fingerprints can be used to validate a connection to a remote server.

These are GitHub's public key fingerprints (in hexadecimal format):

16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48 (RSA)
ad:1c:08:a4:40:e3:6f:9c:f5:66:26:5d:4b:33:5d:8c (DSA)
These are the SHA256 hashes shown in OpenSSH 6.8 and newer (in base64 format):

SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 (RSA)
SHA256:br9IjFspm1vxR3iA35FWE+4VTyz1hYVLIE2t1/CeyWQ (DSA)
```

Comment: The question was for Mac, not windows. I am having the same problem on my Mac. Even if you have git set up nicely with keys so you can clone to any location on your Mac, using the global ssh key setup, VSCode will complain of "Git: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory" and give up. So it appears to not use the global Mac ssh settings at all

Comment: I have a Mac too and it works fine. It's prob bc you updated Mac OS which sometimes makes git lose the passphrase of your ssh key. Try `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, then restart vscode.

Comment: Very useful the tip for the first-time cloning the project in bash to confirm the fingerprint. Works also for GitLab. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is being studiedfor VSCode 1.67 (Apr. 2022) with [issue 145850](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145850):
"Support cloning via SSH by default when picking a repository using the GitHub extension"

> It is already possible today, just paste the SSH URL into the Clone input:
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22350/160397731-10084690-12d3-4397-8a96-c1edc69f4bb0.gif]
>
> With that being said, there's the feature from the GitHub extension which lets you clone repositories without pasting their URL. That's what you're addressing in [#146124](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/146124). By default, the feature uses what GitHub defines to be the clone_url, which happens to always be HTTPS. We also happen to have automatic authentication against GitHub, making the clone via HTTPS really compelling, since the user never has to worry about auth.

So with [PR 146124](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/146124), this should be supported: you will have with VSCode 1.67 a new setting which can set the default URL schemes to use:

> ```
> config.gitProtocol":
> ```
>
> "Controls which protocol is used to clone a GitHub repository",

Answer (score 0):

Just add your SSH keys to the keychain. Next time when you clone the repo SSH will look into the stored keys in keychain and automate the process.

Follow this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically)